# tslint.json unknown compiler option 'extends'

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, typescript

i try to upgrade my WebPart to SharePoint spfx 1.9.1, i follow recommandation generated by  o365 spfx project upgrade --output md > report.md, but when i build my project i get two errors :

```
[16:10:57] Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 322 ms 
 exited with code 1
[16:10:57] 'bundle' errored after 1.99 s
[16:10:57]
[16:10:57] Error - [tslint] error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'extends'.
[16:10:57] Finished subtask 'tslint' after 621 ms
[16:10:57] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Error - 'tsc' sub task errored after 322 ms 
 exited with code 1
Error - [tslint] error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'extends'.
[16:10:58] Project ls2-formation version:2.1.0
[16:10:58] Build tools version:3.8.8
[16:10:58] Node version:v10.16.3
[16:10:58] Total duration:5.12 s
[16:10:58] Task errors:2
```

I think it's caused by tslint.json :

```
{

  "extends": "@microsoft/sp-tslint-rules/base-tslint.json",
  "rules": {
    "class-name": false,
    "export-name": false,
    "forin": false,
    "label-position": false,
    "member-access": true,
    "no-arg": false,
    "no-console": false,
    "no-construct": false,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-eval": false,
    "no-function-expression": true,
    "no-internal-module": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-unnecessary-semicolons": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-with-statement": true,
    "semicolon": true,
    "trailing-comma": false,
    "typedef": false,
    "typedef-whitespace": false,
    "use-named-parameter": true,
    "typeof-compare": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": false
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be coming from the `tsconfig.json` file.

You need to ensure that the file is as below.

Notice, the `extends` attribute that is located above `compilerOptions`

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/@microsoft/rush-stack-compiler-2.9/includes/tsconfig-web.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "inlineSources": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "lib"
  ]
}
```

Comment: it's work, thanks